# KAuth API line of code is throwing an error telling me to convert const char* to non scalar

Tags: c++, authentication

I was following this tutorial:

```
bit.ly/SBMmwp
```

and I got the following error on the first line:

**error: conversion from 'const char [26]' to non-scalar type 'KAuth::Action' requested**

```
KAuth::Action readAction = "org.kde.auth.example.read";

KAuth::ActionReply reply = readAction.execute();
if (reply.failed())
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", QString("KAuth returned an error code: %1").arg(reply.errorCode()));
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Done!", QString("Successfully authenticated!"));
}
```

Error is on the first line: **KAuth::Action readAction = "org.kde.auth.example.read";**

Why is this happening? Is this some error related to misuse of the KAuth API or is it a common C/C++ error. I have no idea how to even convert that **const char[26]** to **non-scalar** type.

---

---

---

---

**@n.m**
No. This is what is on the event in which the main windows (GUI) is created. The full code would be something like:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <kauth.h>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <kauthaction.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    KAuth::Action readAction = "org.kde.auth.example.read";
    KAuth::ActionReply reply = readAction.execute();
    if (reply.failed())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", QString("KAuth returned an error code: %1").arg(reply.errorCode()));
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Done!", QString("Successfully authenticated!"));
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire program you are trying to compile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with KDE, but http://www.purinchu.net/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKAuth_1_1Action.html suggests that you can't assign a string to an "Action". Assuming that 'QString' can be created from a "const char*" (not uncommon for string classes), changing the line to

```
KAuth::Action readAction("org.kde.auth.example.read");
```

might fix it.

Note: Tutorials aren't necessarily correct; their authors aren't always keeping up with changes.

Comment: Just tried it, but it changed the error to "undefined reference to KAuth::Action::Action(Qstring const&)" I suppose then that the problem is with the libraries I downloaded, but I don't know how to get the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

I basically got slapped in the face how it was done. It is done like **Christian** wrote but the reason I was then getting undefined reference blah blah blah was because I needed to link to KDECore libraries. If you are using QT you will have a .pro file. All you have to do is write in it:

```
LIBS += -lkdecore
```

But if you are using CMake for the project, you need these lines in the CMake.txt:

```
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries([name_of_application] kdecore)
```

Or:

```
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries([name_of_application] ${KDE4_KDECORE_LIBS})
```

where **[name_of_application]** is the name of your application to be built (usually the project name). One thing to remember is that if you are using CMake, you must add other libraries as needed for your application. Otherwise you will get more undefined references to other components in your application. For example if I am using QT GUI components and in my application, I would do in the CMake.txt:

```
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(My_Application_Name kdecore ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
```